# Draw and Modify Polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to draw only one polygon, modify it and then save the polygon. I already do the saving. I'm not able to modify the polygon as it snaps.

Here is what I need but I'm not able to make it work. 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

**This is my map:**

```
function map() {
    map = new ol.Map({
          controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions:  ({
        collapsible: true
      })
    }).extend([
      scaleLineControl, new escalaControl(), new quitarContorno()
    ]),
    logo: false,                    /* es global */
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center:ol.proj.fromLonLat([-61.530766,-34.865575]),
      zoom: 7
    })

  });
}
```

**This is the function that draws the polygon and then puts an end to it:**

```
function addInteraction() {

    var value = "polygon";
    noDraw();
     draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
          source: source,
          type: "Polygon",
        });

        map.addInteraction(draw);

        draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
          var feature = evt.feature;
          var p = feature.getGeometry();
          var format = new ol.format.WKT();

          poligonoWKT  = format.writeGeometry(p.transform(ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'),ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326')));
          p.transform(ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'),ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'));
          console.log(poligonoWKT);

          noDraw();

          $("#listgrouparea").show();
          getArea();

        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the modify control.

```
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: source});
      map.addInteraction(modify);
```

Otherwise, post a codepen with your code.